# ¿Cómo mostrar errores de validación para cada elemento de una colección?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mvc, validación, rubygems

Estoy modificando el blog de la [guia](http://www.guiasrails.es/getting_started.html) que acabo de terminar.
Lo que quiero ahora es mostrar si ocurrieron errores al validar comentarios de la misma forma que los muestro al validar artículos.

Ya establecí las restricciones correspondientes en el modelo, y de hecho funciona, ya que al pretender *Comentar* con valores que violen la restricción, el sistema no guarda el comentario, pero el usuario no se entera del por que ocurre eso.

Anexo algunos archivos:

**/app/controllers/articulos_controller.rb**

```
class ArticulosController < ApplicationController

    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secreto", except: [:index, :show]

    def index
        @articulos = Articulo.all
    end

    def show
        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @articulo = Articulo.new
    end

    def edit
        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create

        @articulo = Articulo.new(articulo_params)

        if @articulo.save
            redirect_to @articulo
        else
            render 'new'
        end

    end

    def update

        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])

        if @articulo.update(articulo_params)
            redirect_to @articulo
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy

        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
        @articulo.destroy

        redirect_to articulos_path

    end

    private

    def articulo_params
        params.require(:articulo).permit(:titular, :contenido)
    end

end
```

**/app/controllers/comentarios_controller.rb**

```
class ComentariosController < ApplicationController

    http_basic_authenticate_with name: "dhh", password: "secreto", only: :destroy

    def new
        articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
        @comentario = articulo.comentarios.build
    end

    def create

        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:articulo_id])

        @comentario = @articulo.comentarios.create(comentario_params)

        redirect_to articulo_path(@articulo)

    end

    def destroy

        @articulo = Articulo.find(params[:articulo_id])

        @comentario = @articulo.comentarios.find(params[:id])
        @comentario.destroy

        redirect_to articulo_path(@articulo)

    end

    private

    def comentario_params
        params.require(:comentario).permit(:comentarista, :contenido)
    end

end
```

**/app/models/articulo.rb**

```
class Articulo < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comentarios
    validates :titular, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
    validates :contenido, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10 }
end
```

**/app/models/comentario.rb**

```
class Comentario < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :articulo
    validates :comentarista, presence: true, length: { minimum: 4 }
    validates :contenido, presence: true, length: { minimum: 2 }
end
```

**/app/views/articulos/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @articulo do |f| %>

  <% if @articulo.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@articulo.errors.count, "error") %> han impedido que el artículo sea grabado:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @articulo.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :titular %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :titular %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :contenido %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :contenido %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Guardar' %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

**/app/views/comentarios/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@articulo, @articulo.comentarios.build]) do |f| %>

  <p>
    Nombre<br>
    <%= f.text_field :comentarista %>
  </p>

  <p>
    Comentario<br>
    <%= f.text_area :contenido %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.submit 'Comentar' %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

**Como puedo lograr mostrar dichos errores al validar?**
Desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Primero ese código `@articulo.comentarios.build` del form deberías hacerlo a nivel de controlador y no de la vista, ya que con eso no podrás editar un comentario por ejemplo. El `new` de tu controlador de comentarios debería ser algo como:

```
def new
  articulo = Articulo.find(params[:id])
  @comentario = articulo.comentarios.build
end
```

Luego en el form simplemente usas:

```
<%= form_for @comentario do |f| %>
```

y luego copiar/pegar lo mismo del otro form, pero adaptarlo al modelo de comentarios:

```
  <% if @comentario.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2>
        <%= pluralize(@comentario.errors.count, "error") %> han impedido que el artículo sea grabado:
      </h2>
      <ul>
        <% @comentario.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Pues no me funciona. Me dice _First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty_ en la linea `<%= form_for @comentario do |f| %>` del archivo **/app/views/comentarios/_form.html.erb** que modifique.